# Want to know how many new visitors I get per month

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I got a wifi sensor who scans all the addresses nearby now I want to know how many new people walk in and out every month. so got got addresses and the code needs to see however its a new address or a address that already came by once or more times. The code needs to show me how many new people walked in and out.

```
Select FROM_UnixTime((sensordata1.time + 7200), '%Y-%c') "Datum (Descending)",
COUNT(DISTINCT address) "Bezoekers" 
FROM sensordata1 
WHERE (sensordata1.sensorid = 1908)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY FROM_UnixTime((sensordata1.time + 7200), '%Y-%c') DESC
```

This code is to see how many people have walked in and out this month. And I want to know how many new addresses there were (so the addresses who are not in the database already).

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using two levels of aggregation:

```
select date_format(firstdt, '%Y-%m') as yyyymm, count(*) as firsttimers
from (select sd.address, from_unixtime(min(sd.time)) as firstdt
      from sensordata sd
      group by sd.address
     ) a
group by date_format(firstdt, '%Y-%m')
order by yyyymm;
```